# Flutter How to pass valid context after an async gap?

Tags: flutter, dart

how to pass context in async gap?

```
Future<void> somethingMustWait(BuildContext context) async{
    String? myStringFromAPi;
    
    bool? imustWait;
    
    //api
    await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2), (){
      return 'hello World';
    }).then((value){
      imustWait = true;
      removeOldString();
      myStringFromAPi = value;
    }, onError: (e){
      imustWait = false;
    }).timeout(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    
    //then if result never return, i will wait forever <3
    await Future.doWhile(() => imustWait == null);
    
    // Call context here to show dialog:
    showDialog(context: context, builder: (context)=> AlertDialog(content: Text("yo finished : $myStringFromAPi"),));
    
  }
```

let say, something happen in this async gap, and context no longer valid. maybe because `removeOldString()` function Rebuild ui, or the ui stream to data changes. then my `showDialog` will get invalid context right? how i pass current valid context ?

Comment: what's the issue here?

Comment: got an error : Error: This BuildContext is no longer valid.

Comment: If you have a stateful widget, check if(mounted) { showDialog(context, ...) }

Comment: put the showdialog right after myStringFromAPi = value;

Comment: If I understand it correctly they want to show the dialog even if the widget is not mounted anymore, which would not work if they do the normal mounted check before showing it.

Comment: @spydon that answer is pretty good, but i use go router, so there is no `navigatorKey` option in `MaterialApp.router()`, should i use `router.navigator.context` instead?